# Splitting audio channels using pulseaudio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, ffmpeg, avconv

My mission is record desktop using `avconv (ffmpeg)` + record microphone input + use `sphinx` program which also need the same microphone for voice control.
Now, the problem is that if I start sphinx first, then I can't start avconv (because microphone input is already busy by sphinx), and vice versa.
I wonder, how to use pulseaudio to split channel, or to make some virtual channel to succeed in my mission.

Note: I'm starting `avconv` with next command:

```
    avconv -f x11grab -r 25 -s 1024x768 -i :0.0 -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -ar 22050 output.flv
```

Should I something also change in that command?

Btw. I used recordmydesktop before, but encoding was too slow so I decided to use avconv.
Thank you!